# Multiple branch/chapter management with various access level of information

Tags: groups, smartgroups, roles

I am newbie to CiviCRM.

I an searching for a solution to manage a multiple branches of an organisation with CiviCRM. Multiple branches will be spread across the glob. All the branches should have different types of users.(i.e. Branch Admin,operator etc..).

These branches required to manage their contacts info, membership details, donation details , subscription details.

All the branches data should be visible to admin of head office and all the branch admin/operator should have permission to access their corresponding branch data only.

I have try to implement a this type of structure in CiviCRM with word press. I found a various post to implement this with CiviCRM ACL but it didn't work for me.

If anyone have idea that how should we implement it. Please share with me.
It will be a great if you mention about a steps to achieve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ujival - it really helps the community if you engage with the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [CiviCRM Multisite](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation) with the [Multisite Permissioning extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/multisite-permissioning) for this, and give each organization their own domain.  Within the domain, you can use WordPress roles and/or ACLs to get the various intra-domain roles.

Note that this is NOT a newbie task - multisite CiviCRM is an advanced topic.  Consider hiring outside assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which we have found useful in this scenario is to use the [Related Permissions](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions) extension which turns Permissions Relationships in to true ACLs and can be used in a multi-tiered approach eg:

**Global Officer** has a permissioned relationship to Global Organisation which has a permissioned relationship to a National Organisation which has a permissioned relationship to Local Organisation which has a permissioned relationship to Local Contacts and hence Global Officer sees all Local Contacts across the globe, as well as any National contacts (if the system allows for contacts that are at national but not local level, eg national 'officers')

Then at the next step down

**National Officer** has a permissioned relationship to a National Organisation which has a permissioned relationship to Local Organisation which has a permissioned relationship to Local Contacts and hence the National Officer sees only/all local contacts that relate to the country.

And going further down the chain,

**Local Officer** has a permissioned relationship to Local Organisation which has a permissioned relationship to Local Contacts and hence the Local Officer only sees their 'local contacts'

Comment: Do you have any hosted demo with Related permissions extensions ?

Comment: No but this doesn't involve a lot of work to set up. See my other comments in Chat

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look at CiviCon a few years back in SF - There were presentations from Colorado Bicycle Coalition that mirrored your scenario - different regional groups that had access to their regional info - and a Master that could overlook all - this was done with Drupal and Civi - good luck

Answer (score 0):

There's now an extension called [Custom Permission](https://civicrm.org/blog/skornien/custom-permission-extension-for-multi-level-organization) which handles multi-level branch/chapter permissions.